# SQL - Use of Group By with case

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error

I have often seen CASE statements being written inside GROUP BY in SQL whenever one writes CASE statements after SELECT statements. Is it a rule ?Or, if it carries some significance then when should one use CASE statements inside GROUP BY in SQL?

Eg.

*

```
SELECT supplier_id,
CASE
  WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Hardware' THEN 'North office'
  WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Software' THEN 'South office'
END
FROM suppliers;
GROUP BY supplier_id
    CASE
         WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Hardware' THEN 'North office'
         WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Software' THEN 'South office'
    END*
```

When I remove CASE statements,written within GROUP BY, the query doesn't produce desired result. Why does this happen?

Comment: You don't need to group by value, just group by the filed!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: That is not always true - there are circumstances when the CASE statement must be in the GROUP BY to generate the correct result-set, and sometimes even for the query to execute.

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: You have a `;` in `FROM` like `FROM suppliers;`. Is that a typo?

Comment: What result is desired for rows where `supplier_name <> 'IBM'`? Are you intending to NULL-ify those rows, or omit them entirely?

Answer (score 3):

Most database engines have requirements for an aggregation query.  All columns in the `select` must either be in the `group by` clause or wrapped in aggregation functions (such as `min()`, `max()`, etc.).

This requirement is relaxed in two cases.  MySQL will allow un-aggregated columns as an extension.  It chooses an arbitrary value.  THe SQL standard allows you to group by a unique id in a table and then reference other columns (technically called "functionally dependent").

So, in most databases, removing the `case` from the `group by` will generate an error.  In MySQL, it will return one row per `supplier_id` with an arbitrary value for the second column.

For the query in your question, though, it is easier to write:

```
SELECT distinct supplier_id,
       (CASE WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Hardware' THEN 'North office'
             WHEN supplier_name = 'IBM' and supplier_type = 'Software' THEN 'South office'
        END)
FROM suppliers;
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. have a question here: in general is it at all recommended/make sense to use `group by` without doing any aggregation. I would say NO since that's the main purpose of `group by`. Wanted to know if I am right?

Comment: @Rahul . . . To be honest, I *prefer* `group by` over `select distinct`.  The latter tends to be too confusing, because many people don't realize that `distinct` always applies to all columns in the `select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry but I don't understand your answer. Please explain again- why it is necessary to write CASE statements again within GROUP BY clause.

Comment: (1) In most databases, you will get a syntax error if you don't.  (2) In MySQL, the values used for the expression will come from some arbitrary row, and the query will probably not do what you intend.